# How I can post link in html to youtube comment

Tags: php, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to post a html link on YouTube comment but Some how I could not do that thing. It always shows html codes on the comment section. I am using php function

```php
$comment = '<a href="http://shawon.in">Shawon</a>';
$commen =  html_entity_decode($comment);
```

It shows the output as the html codes in `$comment`. Or tell me which content-type will work for this.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem it is not possible: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments

> A comment is a text response to a video. Logged-in users can add comments to a video but cannot modify or delete those comments. In addition, please note that **YouTube will convert any HTML markup that appears in a comment into plain text**. Typically, a user would add a comment to a video after watching that video.